# JSF: JS redirection doesn't work for h:commandButton onclick event

Tags: jsf, button, redirect, ajax4jsf

Migrating from `a4j:commandLink` to `h:commandButton` problem.

this working case:

```
<a4j:commandLink  event="onclick" onclick="if (!confirm('#{resourceBundle.agreement_cancel_message}')) return false;" oncomplete="window.location.href='menu?agreementId='+ agreementId;"/>
```

this case with `h:commandButton` doesn't work,current page just refreshed:

```
<h:commandButton onclick="if (!confirm('#{resourceBundle.agreement_cancel_message}')) return false;window.location.href='menu?agreementId='+ agreementId;"/>
```

As I know,I can't use `oncomplete` for `h:commandButton` at all.

Answer (score 3):

You need to *always* `return false` in order to prevent the button's default action (submitting the form).

```
<h:commandButton onclick="if(confirm('#{resourceBundle.agreement_cancel_message}'))window.location.href='menu?agreementId='+ agreementId;return false;"/>
```

*(putting `{}` around the `if` body may improve readability)*

By the way, you seem to never invoke a bean action method. Why are you using `<h:commandButton>` at all?

```
<button onclick="if(confirm('#{resourceBundle.agreement_cancel_message}'))window.location.href='menu?agreementId='+ agreementId;return false;"/>
```

Comment: how to say,because it's like our project policy - to decrease a4j:command* usage

Comment: That would not be possible because you're changing the current location by JS.

Answer (score 0):

Page is refreshed because default event handler of input is working.

Try preventing input's submit behavior (return false; at the end):

```
<h:commandButton onclick="if (!confirm('#{resourceBundle.agreement_cancel_message}')) return false;window.location.href='menu?agreementId='+ agreementId; return false;"/>
```